# Error on application install: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, software-installation, rpm

When I executed a command to install an application, the following error occurred

```
  /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I was not aware on how to fix this problem. I found the following solution online:

```
yum install glibc.i686
```

or

```
yum install glibc.i386
```

But bad luck, this did not work at all. It was throwing the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
No package glibc.i686 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Again I tried to resolve this and got some solutions from net

> Download glibc rpm packge for centos 6 and install them.

I downloaded the following packages:

```
glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
glibc-devel-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
glibc-headers-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
glibc-static-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
glibc-utils-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
```

And tried to install with following command:

```
yum install glibc.i686
rpm -U glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
rpm -ivh glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
```

None of them solved my problem. I got following message:

```
[root@s7 tmp_glibc]# rpm -ivh glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
    error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6 is needed by glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libfreebl3.so is needed by glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) is needed by glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
```

To resolve the dependency problem I tried to install "glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm", but again bad luck runs and gives error:

```
[root@s7 tmp_glibc]# rpm -ivh glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc = 2.12-1.80.el6 is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libc.so.6 is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.1) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libcap.so.2 is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2 is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686
```

Can anyone please help me by resolving this issue?

More Details:
Operating System: centos 6.3
Yum installed packege list:

```
[root@s7 tmp_glibc]# yum list installed glibc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Installed Packages
glibc.x86_64
```

Comment: What application did you try to install in the first place by the way?

Answer (score 5):

Try first to search for the package:

> yum search glibc

This will provide all the packages that contain glibc.
Second, what application are you installation that gives you the error?

you can also perform the following

> yum whatprovides /lib/ld-linux.so.2

This will tell you what package contains the required file so you can just issue yum install

Answer (score 0):

just had same problem with android sdk on 64 bit centos 6
For me it worked this way:

```
wget ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.3/os/i386/Packages/glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
wget ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.3/os/i386/Packages/glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
yum install nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-11.el6.i686
rpm -Uhv glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.i686.rpm
```

Also to make adnroid sdk working I had to install:

```
yum install zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.i686 libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.i686
```